# Mysql Dynamic crosstab Pivot comparison on one table

Tags: mysql

I have a many to many table setup. This is an example of table I am focusing on.

many_to_many_id,    foreign_key_id
1,  1
1,  2
1,  3
2,  1
2,  2
3,  1
3,  4

I need to given `many_to_many_id` 1 find any other `many_to_many_ids` that have matching foreign keys that exist within the first set. Given the first set 1, 2, 3 attached to `many_to_many_id` would return 2 as 1, and 2 are inside the set, but 3 would not be returned as 4 is not part of the test set. My boss has said I should use a dynamic cross tab to create two tables to compare with a join. I have looked for examples but they have not been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a few simple sub-queries. The first will make sure that for each `many_to_many_id` there is at least one `foreign_key_id` in the set you're looking for (1, 2, 3) and the second will make sure there *isn't* even one `foreign_key_id` *not* in the set you're looking for.

```
SET @search_id = 1;

SELECT m.many_to_many_id FROM SampleTable m
WHERE m.many_to_many_id != @search_id
AND     EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM SampleTable a WHERE a.many_to_many_id = m.many_to_many_id AND a.foreign_key_id IN ( SELECT b.foreign_key_id FROM SampleTable b WHERE b.many_to_many_id = @search_id ) )
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM SampleTable a WHERE a.many_to_many_id = m.many_to_many_id AND a.foreign_key_id NOT IN ( SELECT b.foreign_key_id FROM SampleTable b WHERE b.many_to_many_id = @search_id ) )
GROUP BY m.many_to_many_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bc76/2)